# Unable to render here map if container uses percentage in width/height

Tags: here-api

if i use the following as the container,

```
<div style="width: 1200px; height: 600px; margin:0 auto;" id="mapContainer"></div>
```

so the map renders correctly.

but i don't want to use fix width or height, so i change it to use a class

```
.here-maps {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

the div is all blank. but i can see it's rendered anyhow, but just not displayed,

```
<div class="here-maps" id="mapContainer" ng-show="showMap" style=""><div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;"><div style="z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; touch-action: none;"><div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 0;"><canvas width="1371" height="1" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1371px; height: 0px;"></canvas><div style="position: absolute; width: 1371px; height: 0px;"></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; bottom: 4em; left: 0.5em; z-index: 1; height: 0px; direction: ltr; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 11px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; pointer-events: none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="3em" height="2.2em" viewBox="0 0 540 430"><path d="M 0,303 127,430 h 77 l -53,-53 c -19,-18 -24,-31 -13,-43 8,-9 18,-8 30,3 l 64,65 39,-39 -69,-70 c -28,-28 -55,-34 -81,-7 -16,15 -18,30 -17,44 L 38,265 0,303 z m 322,-97 c -41,-41 -79,-43 -113,-9 -34,34 -28,77 5,110 41,41 86,34 120,0 17,-16 26,-31 30,-41 l -34,-19 c -5,9 -12,20 -21,28 -19,19 -36,19 -48,9 l 70,-69 -9,-8 z m -85,57 c -11,-12 -11,-26 0,-37 11,-11 24,-11 38,0 l -38,37 z m 138,-3 39,-39 -42,-42 C 337,145 347,127 355,119 361,113 367,109 371,108 L 339,71 c -2,1 -7,5 -12,9 -13,14 -17,35 -13,49 L 297,114 263,148 374,260 z M 494,34 C 453,-8 415,-10 381,25 c -33,33 -25,79 6,109 41,41 85,35 119,1 20,-20 30,-39 32,-48 L 505,68 c -4,9 -13,24 -24,34 -18,19 -36,19 -48,9 L 503,42 494,34 z m -85,57 c -11,-12 -11,-26 0,-37 11,-11 24,-11 37,0 l -37,37 z" style="fill: rgb(27, 70, 141);"></path></svg></div><div style="-webkit-user-select: none; position: relative; top: 2.2em; padding-left: 1px;"><span unselectable="on">© 1987–2016 HERE | </span><a target="_blank" href="http://here.com/terms" style="color: inherit;">Terms of use</a><span style="color: inherit; display: none;"> | <a target="_blank" style="color: inherit;">Report image</a></span></div></div><div class="H_ui"><div class="H_l_top H_l_left"><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_horizontal"></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_vertical"></div></div><div class="H_l_top H_l_right"><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_horizontal"></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_vertical"></div></div><div class="H_l_bottom H_l_left"><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_vertical"></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_horizontal"></div></div><div class="H_l_bottom H_l_right"><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_vertical"></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_horizontal"><div class="H_ctl H_scalebar" title="Change to miles" style="direction: ltr;"><svg height="28" version="1.1" class="H_scalebar_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="79"><polyline style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-width:4;stroke-opacity:0.8" points="2 19 2 26 77 26 77 19"></polyline><polyline style="fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:2" points="2 20 2 26 77 26 77 20"></polyline><text style="stroke:white;stroke-width:2;stroke-opacity:0.8;text-anchor:end;font: bold 10px 'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" x="71" y="22">10000 km</text><text style="text-anchor:end;font: bold 10px 'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:black;" x="71" y="22">10000 km</text></svg></div><div class="H_ctl"><div class="H_btn" title="Choose view"><svg version="1.1" class="H_icon" viewBox="0 0 26 26"><polygon points="19,14 17,14 19,16 13,19 6,16 9,14 7,14 3,16 13,21 23,16"></polygon><polygon points="13,15 3,10 13,5 23,10"></polygon></svg></div><div class="H_overlay"><div class="H_rdo"><div class="H_rdo_title">Choose view</div><div class="H_rdo_buttons"><div class="H_btn H_active">Map view</div><div class="H_btn">Satellite</div><div class="H_btn">Terrain</div></div></div><div class="H_btn">Traffic conditions</div><div class="H_btn">Public transport</div><div class="H_btn">Show traffic incidents</div></div></div></div></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_top H_l_center H_l_horizontal" style="margin-left: 0px;"></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_left H_l_middle H_l_vertical" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_right H_l_middle H_l_vertical" style="margin-top: -40px;"><div class="H_ctl H_zoom H_grp"><div class="H_btn" title="Zoom in"><svg class="H_icon" viewBox="0 0 25 25"><path d="M 18.5,11 H 14 V 6.5 c 0,-.8 -.7,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5 -.8,0 -1.5,.7 -1.5,1.5 V 11 H 6.5 C 5.7,11 5,11.7 5,12.5 5,13.3 5.7,14 6.5,14 H 11 v 4.5 c 0,.8 .7,1.5 1.5,1.5 .8,0 1.5,-.7 1.5,-1.5 V 14 h 4.5 C 19.3,14 20,13.3 20,12.5 20,11.7 19.3,11 18.5,11 z"></path></svg></div><div class="H_btn" title="Zoom out"><svg class="H_icon" viewBox="0 0 25 25"><path d="m 6.5,11 h 12 c .8,0 1.5,.7 1.5,1.5 0,.8 -.7,1.5 -1.5,1.5 H 6.5 C 5.7,14 5,13.3 5,12.5 5,11.7 5.67,11 6.5,11 z"></path></svg></div></div></div><div class="H_l_anchor H_l_bottom H_l_center H_l_horizontal" style="margin-left: 0px;"></div></div></div></div>
```

i am not taking care of the resize scenario yet. 
any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the ng-show will asynchronously make the browser recalcualate the div's size but the HERE map implementation doesn't resize automatically. In the resulting HTML you can see that the canvas element (where the map is rendered) has a height of 1, which is definitely not the right size.

Can you try calling map.getViewport()[.resize()](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-viewport.html#h-map-viewport__resize) after the map div is `ng-show`n to make the map recalculate it's size?

Something like

```
$scope.$watch('showMap', function(shown) {
    if(shown) map.getViewport().resize();
});
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I should have taken a closer look at what is going on with your CSS. I put your code in a fiddle, and indeed the map does not render at the right size. For me the mapContainer is 0 pixels high, which is correct. The div never gets a height it can apply - just a bottom padding of 56.25% (but fifty-odd percent of what?). So, I played around with it and came up with this:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.here-maps {
  width: 100%;
  height: 43.75%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

First, I made html and body tag fill the height of the window. Then, instead of bottom padding just used height (100%-56.25%). Does that resemble what you were looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/xv0Ly9ek/

Comment: thanks for the answer. however i don't think ng-show is the cause. i have eliminate the ng-show but it's still the same. looks like when width/height is using percentage, and the map can't show correctly.